# Prevent scrolling from finger swipe on parent listbox

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I have a listbox with a few items. One of the Listboxitems contains a listview. When I scroll in the listview, the listbox also scrolls. How can I prevent scrolling in the parent listbox while scrolling in the listview?

I'm currently trying things out now and going through the embacadero wiki, but I would be much appreciative if someone could help me out if the answer is quick - as I'm sure it is and I am just overlooking something.

Comment: Putting one scrolling list inside another scrolling list is probably not going to work out well. Could you not use some kind on master/detail view within the list box? Use different styles to reflect the detail items.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of came to that conclusion as well that I should go a different route. I will probably use a comboEdit instead and implement an auto complete feature or something. Will keep question up, because it would still be nice to know how to disable scrolling on a listbox.